# R console crashes when using removeBimeraDenovo function

Tags: r, dna-sequence, fastq

I am using this DADA2 Pipeline tutorial for the first time: 
https://benjjneb.github.io/dada2/tutorial.html

I am a complete novice (MSc biotechnology student) learning to conduct a microbiota analysis using DADA2 in R, and then Phyloseq.

I have trimmed and filtered my fastq data, learned the error rates, applied the core sample inference algorithm to the filtered and trimmed sequence data, merged the paired reads...

However, after constructing the sequence variant table, I try to  remove chimeras using this input:

```
seqtab.nochim <- removeBimeraDenovo(seqtab, method="consensus", multithread=TRUE, verbose=TRUE)
dim(seqtab.nochim)
```

R crashes every time.

I have never used any coding software before. This is my first attempt at writing code.

I really would appreciate simplified and overly informative answers.

Thank you!

My expected results should look something like this:

### [1]  20 232

and after I receive that info, I would input this:

```
sum(seqtab.nochim)/sum(seqtab)
```

Comment: Since this issue seems to specific to that package, I think you would be better off filing an issue with the package developer at their github issues page: https://github.com/benjjneb/dada2/issues

Comment: Thank you. It appears someone else had the same issue, although it does not appear to be resolved!